# "SqlCommandTimeout" value="120" SQL Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Could you please help me, why I am getting this error.
Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

in config file we already have `<add key="SqlCommandTimeout" value="120" />` But still we are getting that error in Production, please help me what could be the cause for this.
This is the stack trace info -

```
<error Source="System.Transactions" TargetSite="Void EndCommit(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction)">The transaction is in doubt.</error>
<error Source=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" TargetSite="Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1[System.Action])">Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.</error>
<error Source="" TargetSite="">The wait operation timed out</error>
<stack> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)</stack>
<stack> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)</stack>
```

Comment: It is most likely because you got too much happening within your SQL box for it's size, so it takes longer than 2 minutes for the command to execute due to locking on a table. If you're logging to SQL this can happen a lot, look at producer-consumer pattern to queue logs locally rather than wait for them to go to SQL directly

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes we are logging directly to SQL. Sorry I did not understand this -  producer-consumer pattern to queue logs locally rather than wait for them to go to SQL directly , Can you please explain me what I need to verify on this

Comment: You just need to rearchitect your app so that rather than logs going to SQL, they go into a queue. Or increase your SQL box performance (get more RAM, faster SSD etc.). Or reduce number of logs in your application.

Comment: you can incresse timeout for each query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1